# Logging System from txt file to database

Tags: mysql, database-design

Iam thinking changing the log file into database table.

I execute multiple `shell_exec` and it run in the background, example:

```
<?php
 shell_exec("php process.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
 shell_exec("php process.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
 shell_exec("php process.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
 shell_exec("php process.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
?>
```

While `process.php` is running/looping - it will generate a log, assume process ID is 123

log_123.txt File:

```
-----------------------------------------
Process ID: 123
- Loggin In
- Logged OK
- Checking xxxx (xxxxx)
- Sending Info
- Received xxxx 25252525
- Completed
------------------------------------------
Process ID: 123
- Loggin In
- Logged OK
- Checking xxxx (xxxxx)
- Sending Info
- Received xxxx 23424
- Completed
------------------------------------------
Process ID: 123
- Loggin In
- Logged OK
- Checking xxxx (xxxxx)
- FAIL
------------------------------------------
```

(Each process have a log file)

Now I wanted to change text files logging into database table log, what is the best way to do this?

I came up with this solution:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `log` (
  `log_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `process_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `process_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `log_output` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `log_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: What code have you come up with so far? You seem to have a good start.

Comment: @Drazisil, In the process.php there is a while loop: `file_put_contents("log_". posix_getpid() . ".txt", $print, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);`  - this will generate a log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the table, you have the file. It sounds like you just need to modify the process.php file to update your database instead of the test file.

If you are using mysql http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php is a good place to start.

Comment: Yes I know that! I am saying if the design design I have created is fine?

Comment: So the actual question was "Given my data, do you think this is a good table design?" In that case, yes. You may want to make your question a little clearer next time.